# php google api contacts 403 in php, working with postman

Tags: php, google-api

I want to query the google rest api endpoint to get user contacts:

```
public static function getContacts(string $token) {
        $url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=999999";
        $opts = [
            "http" => [
                "method" => "GET",
                "header" => "Authorization: Bearer {$token}"
            ]
        ];
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($opts));
        $contacts = json_decode($response);
        return $contacts;
    }
```

However, the request returns 403 even thought the token is valid and the request works when sending it via Postman.

Comment: Are you sure the token is correct? The error 403 means your token has no access to the requested resource. What is the request you're sending with postman? Post it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use curl to call api. i think it will work fine there.
```